# Spring MVC - Require a header without using the value?

Tags: spring, rest

I know that I can require a header by using @RequestHeader like this

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/hello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> hello(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String accessToken) {
        //Do something here...
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

This works as intended. But since Springs security context will contain my accessToken, and is threadsafe, rather than passing the token around it around I can do something like this and fetch the token when I need it instead:

```
   public String getAccessToken() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
            JwtAuthenticationToken token = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            return token.getToken().getTokenValue();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected JwtAuthenticationToken");
    }
```

So I was wondering if I can require the header without also defining the method argument? It wouldn't make any functional difference, but I think it makes the code cleaner. In Go there is the ["blank identifier"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier)  which can be used in cases like this, but as far as I know there is no such think in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by listing the header in your `@PostMapping` annotation:

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/hello",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    headers = {"Authorization"}
)
public ResponseEntity<Void> hello() {
    // ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

This would only map your handler method on requests with that header present. If you don't have a handler for requests missing that header, those will probably result in a 404.